# How to access IP Camera from remote network without Port Forwarding

Tags: iot

Most of the IP Camera Manufactures (like D-link) have their own mobile application in market and they are able to access the cameras form remote network without port forwarding or anything. But how they are doing it? Anyone please help me on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those scenarios, IP cameras are sending stream to another stream engine on cloud. And our app are getting data from the stream engine with or without authentication mechanism.
Apps are not connected pear to pear with the Camera. Stream Engine comes in between both for data transmission.
[Here is one example of streaming engine on cloud](https://www.wowza.com/)

Comment: Hi Samrat. Already heard about WOWZA. And you confirmed it. Thank You.

Comment: your welcome, wowza media is paid, some open source things like that are also available, you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a vpn and connecting that way?

http://www.codingepiphany.com/2015/02/10/easy-secure-home-ip-camera-access-with-your-own-vpn/

Comment: No @Fin. I will try that. Will it work like their's?

Comment: I gone through the link that you suggested. But after some setup, even there we are doing Port forwarding staff in that. Actually, what I'm expecting is kind of zero conf.